# Installing ukuu on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation

Can you help me? I'm trying to install ukuu to upgrade my kernel. I'm using this tutorial:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ukuu
```

I'm following this guide from https://github.com/teejee2008/ukuu (official page)

After running all commands, I get this on my terminal:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ukuu
```

System details:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please see what's available from http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/ ... Seems to be no `ukuu` any more.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm the issue, but you can compile it on your own following the instructions (https://github.com/teejee2008/ukuu) :

```
sudo apt-get install libgee-0.8-dev libjson-glib-dev libvte-2.91-dev valac git
git clone https://github.com/teejee2008/ukuu.git
cd ukuu
make all
sudo make install
```

Comment: Did you try it? Seems that isn't working installing manually, after trying running commands, some issues happens, like not upgrading the kernel, and showing a lot of errors on terminal.

Comment: I needed ukuu too and I simply did the above, everything worked fine on Ubuntu 18.04